# CoreBluetooth macOS app, connecting iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth

Here is my code:

```
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("powered on")
        
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected")
    }
}
```

I am running this app on macOS, and I'm trying to discover my iPhone device, but so far I'm not able to. My iPhone is paired to my macOS via Bluetooth, but it's not getting discovered in the `didDiscover` function. It is printing stuff to the console, but my iPhone device never gets printed, and I'm not sure how do I even identify my iPhone device in the `didDiscover` function so I'm asking for help here.

Comment: What app are you running on the iPhone that is advertising a BLE service? When you say "paired to my macOS via Bluetooth," what does that mean to you? There are two kinds of "Bluetooth." CoreBluetooth only relates to BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).

Comment: I went into bluetooth settings and paired my iPhone with my macbook

Comment: That's unrelated to BLE or Core Bluetooth. Those are classic (BR/EDR) connections. There's no direct access to that on iPhone except for GATT over BR/EDR (added in iOS 13). But you need to write a service on both sides that support that. It's not general purpose Classic Bluetooth. It's unfortunate the Bluetooth committee named two unrelated protocols with the same name; it creates a lot of confusion.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for using CoreBluetooth to make it possible to for my macbook to communicate with my iPhone?

Comment: In what way do you want them to communicate? If you mean to write a Mac app and an iPhone app that speak BLE to each other, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Comment: The desired communication would be an iPhone app that streams IMU data from iPhone to MacBook app for further processing.

Comment: BLE may be ok for that. The Core Bluetooth guide would be the right introduction. But if this is only for Mac and iOS, I'd look at MultipeerConnectivity instead. It's generally easier to use, particularly if you're not familiar with the complexities of BLE.